# nunit-console.exe hangs after finishing test run

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

We got a problem with NUnit 2.5.3: nunit-console.exe does not return after finishing all tests. The process hangs forever.

Example: All tests succeed, but it keeps doing something. Output:

```
Runtime Environment -

OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3
CLR Version: 2.0.50727.3603 ( Net 2.0.50727.3603 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-2.0.50727.3603
.................................................................................
Tests run: 119, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 60,5217744 seconds
Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```

It does however work with the Nunit gui version.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

bja

Comment: Are you using a mocking/isolation framework? Are these new tests? Is there a specific test which reproduces it when it's executed alone?

Comment: No mocking/isolation. Tests worked with MSTest, we are switching to NUnit. No, this issue only occurs, when all tests run together. Each fixture on its own runs to completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any multi-threading? I've had issues with threads not completing correctly and causing this.

Comment: but all test finish successfully. Is it a TearDown method then?

Comment: Are you able to attach to the NUnit process when it's hanging and break? This may give you insight into exactly what the runner is doing.

Comment: Thx all - problem solved. There were some issues with multi-threading and open sockets :) Using IDisposable properly solved the problem.